# Missing required parameters for Route and Controller [Route: codigos_barra.create] but I am passing the parameters

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I have a problem because when the button *`generate barcode`* is clicked, 
this throws me `missing required parameters` error, despite the fact that the parameter passed to the route and the controller, as you can see.

**What could be the problem?**

1. **controller method that sends array to the blade**

   ```
   $empresas = Empresa::all();
   $id_empresa = (int)$request->get('empresa');
   $equipos = Equipo::get_equipos_sin_barcode($id_empresa);
   return view('equipos.codigos_barra.index', compact('empresas', 'equipos'));
   ```
2. **Blade**

   ```
   <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 65%;">
       <form action="{{route('codigos_barra.create', $equipos)}}" class="form-inline" method="GET">
           <button class="btn btn-primary shadow" type="submit">
               <i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i>Generar QR
           </button>
       </form>
   </div>
   ```
3. **Route**

   ```
     Route::get('codigos_barra/{equipos}/create', 'CodigoBarraController@create')->name('codigos_barra.create')->middleware('auth','roles:1');
   ```
4. **Method that receives the parameter**

> ```
>   public function create($equipos)
> {
>
>     return view('equipos.codigos_barra.create');
> }
> ```

1. **dd($equipos)**

> ```
>    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#391 ▼
>   #items: array:3 [▼
>     0 => App\Equipo {#396 ▶}
>     1 => App\Equipo {#376 ▶}
>     2 => App\Equipo {#397 ▶}
>   ]
> }
> ```

---

***This is the first equipo array***

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#391 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Equipo {#396 ▼
      #fillable: array:17 [▼
        0 => "nombre_equipo"
        1 => "id_empresa"
        2 => "serie"
        3 => "marca"
        4 => "modelo"
        5 => "id_sede"
        6 => "id_tipo_equipo"
        7 => "foto"
        8 => "registro_invima"
        9 => "id_proveedor"
        10 => "consecutivo"
        11 => "descripcion"
        12 => "id_ubicacion"
        13 => "id_riesgo"
        14 => "id_usuario_crea"
        15 => "id_estado_equipo"
        16 => "ind_baja"
      ]
      #table: "equipos"
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:28 [▶]
      #original: array:28 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "id_tipo_equipo" => 2
        "id_empresa" => 1
        "id_sede" => 5
        "id_ubicacion" => 1
        "id_proveedor" => 1
        "id_estado_equipo" => 1
        "id_usuario_crea" => 1
        "id_riesgo" => 1
        "nombre_equipo" => "LENSOMETRO"
        "consecutivo" => "VGR-000157"
        "descripcion" => "LENSOMETRO"
        "serie" => "39088839"
        "marca" => "TOPCON"
        "modelo" => "CL-200"
        "valor_compra" => null
        "fecha_compra" => null
        "registro_invima" => "N/A"
        "id_funcion" => null
        "estado" => "1"
        "ind_baja" => 0
        "ind_codigo_barras" => null
        "codigo_barras" => null
        "foto" => "public/p9JIbQvzch5gEizWK39NqwcGtvZIF2bL0m8twynM.jpeg"
        "created_at" => "2020-01-11 10:10:42"
        "updated_at" => "2020-01-11 10:10:43"
        "empresa" => "COVGR S.A.S"
        "estado_equipo" => "Activo"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

Comment: the problem is in your create blade page as you are saying you get the error when you click on generate button

Comment: Try to inspect the form action and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that your issue is with this line

```
$equipos = Equipo::get_equipos_sin_barcode($id_empresa); // This must return an ID or slug to pass it later to the route {{route('codigos_barra.create', $equipos)}}
```

Since $equipos return an array of items you can do

```
@foreach($equipos as $equipo) 
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 65%;">
   <form action="{{route('codigos_barra.create', $equipo->id)}}" class="form-inline" method="GET"> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary shadow" type="submit"> 
      <i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i>Generar QR 
      </button> 
   </form>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you paste here the dump($equipos) result ?

Comment: Yes, it is because I am passing a multidimensional array, how do I pass the multidimensional array to the path? Thank you

Comment: You can't , you must pass only simple strings (ID, UUID, Slug...) as route parameters 
See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters

Comment: So, what can i do?

Comment: Thank you, but I want to pass the whole set, because in the way you told me, I threw three buttons and clicking on one of them only gives me the equipo id.

Comment: Yes this is the  point you should NOT pass an array of $equipos to your blade view from the controller. It must be one single item (object).

If you would like to fix it go here $equipos = Equipo::get_equipos_sin_barcode($id_empresa); and change it to smth like that
$unEquipo = Equipo::first($id_empresa); // this return only one item. Then you can use {{route('codigos_barra.create', $unEquipo->id)}} in your blade